# Is there a way to generate installation file for iPhone without Apple Developer Account from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin

I want to generate IPA file and want to upload to a private webpage in my job.

My Apple Developer Account is expired and I search for a way to create installation file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Free provisioning** allows Xamarin.iOS developers to deploy and test their apps on iOS devices without being part of the Apple Developer Program. While simulator testing is valuable and convenient.

And you can check the link below to see get more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=windows

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, an Apple Account is always required.

You can now test on your device with a free Apple Developer Account. Maybe you can downgrade your existing account, or create a new one.

See: https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/